# Copy and paste based on a cell change

Tags: excel, vba

I have a count down timer in excel and as it counts down i would like to copy and paste  range of cells to another, based on 60 mins and  minute to the end i have written the time i would like the macro to do this in j1 and input the ranges but i cant get it to work.

```
Sub MyMacro(my_macro)

If Cells(4, 6) = j1 Then

Range("g9:G64").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("L9:l64").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False

If Not apllication.insersect(Range(j1), Range(target.Address)) Is Nothing 
Then

End Sub
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are those typos, or is that really the code you are trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K4")) Is Nothing Then
    If Range("K4") < Range("J1") Then
        Range("G9:G64").Copy
        Range("L9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: hello thank you for your rapid response, i have put the code into the sheet and it doesn't seem to do anything im definetly missing something as you can tell im quiete new to code

Comment: F4 is a count down clock and J1 is a value ive in put the idea is when the count down hit 1 minute to go it records the information, so ideally if i could i would like to automate it because eventually this will be running on several computers, many thanks again

Comment: the count down timer from a website, basically the information with in the spread sheet is constantly updating from bet angel, which is an affiliate of bet fair  so the countdown timer is in an accordance with a event starting soon

Comment: great i have it working many thanks quick question if i wanted to have the macro check every  seconds would i use this command

Comment: alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventMacro"